# basic_string<CharT> vs. CharT*

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-deduction, stdstring

This is a FAQ, yet I could not find a satisfying answer.  In my project we support `std::string` and now have to also support wide strings.  So we want to move to `basic_string`, but then, things stop working nicely and parameters need to be spelled out explicitly:

```
#include <string>

template <typename CharT, typename Traits, typename Allocator>
void
foo(const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>&)
{}

template void foo(const std::string&);

// template void
// foo<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>(const std::string&);

void bar(const std::string& s)
{}

int main()
{
  bar("abc");
  foo<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>("def");
  foo("def");
}
```

OK, it fails for the well-known reason:

```
clang++-mp-3.5 -Wall -std=c++11 foo.cc 
foo.cc:20:3: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
  foo("def");
  ^~~
foo.cc:5:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
      'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1, type-parameter-0-2>'
      against 'char const[4]'
foo(const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>&)
^
```

What I don't get it why does it work for `bar`?  Why doesn't the explicit instantiation of `foo` for `char` (either with explicit template parameters or with deduction) suffice to work around this problem?

It seems that it means that instead of using templates and `basic_string` in the exposed API, we will have to use it as an implementation detail, but expose the user with overloads for `std::string`, `std::wstring`, etc. which is a shame.

Thanks!

Comment: The explicit version of `foo` works with clang3.5, only the one with parameter deduction fails (the last line), because well it can't deduce the parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `bar("abc")` there is an implicit conversion from `char const[4]` to `std::string`. `foo` differs from `bar` in that it's not actually a function but a function *template*. Its template arguments need to be known in order to build the correct function.

The first call to `foo` explicitly provides the template arguments, so it builds a function that looks like this:

```
void foo(const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>&);
```

The implicit conversion kicks in and everything is fine.

The third call does not provide the template arguments, so the compiler has to figure out the type of `CharT`, `Traits` and `Allocator` from the type `char const[4]`. This type doesn't carry that information with it, so deduction fails and overload resolution cannot find the correct function.

Comment: I guess I am just really frustrated that overloaded functions and explicitly instantiated function templates don't behave equally.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Does this work for you:

```
template <typename StringT>
void foo(const StringT& the_string)
{
    typedef decltype(the_string[0]) CharT;
    // do the work
}
```

That can deduce `StringT` as `std::string`, `std::wstring`, `const char[N]`, `const wchar_t[N]`, `std::vector<char>` etc.  And if you want implicit conversions of C-style strings to std::string beforehand, so you can use the member functions common to all STL collections, add a forwarding overload that catches the arrays:

```
template <typename CharT, size_t N>
void foo(const CharT (&char_array_or_literal)[N])
{
    foo(std::basic_string<CharT>(char_array_or_literal));
}
```

And maybe another for character pointers:

```
template <typename CharT>
void foo(const CharT* char_ptr)
{
    foo(std::basic_string<CharT>(char_ptr));
}
```

If on the other hand, you need all functions of `basic_string`, then the broad template should be used for forwarding:

```
template <typename CharT, typename Traits, typename Allocator>
void foo(const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& the_string)
{
    // the real work is done here
}

template <typename StringLikeT>
void foo(const StringLikeT& the_string_like_thing)
{
    typedef decltype(the_string_like_thing[0]) CharT;
    // this turns string literals, arrays, pointers, vectors, std::array, all into basic_string
    foo(basic_string<CharT>(&the_string_like_thing[0]));
}
```

Comment: I think this answer makes it clearest what is going on - the code from the question is templated on the wrong thing (details of basic_string) rather than the concept of a string. With the solution in this answer, even std::array<char, ...> and std::vector<char> can be passed in. And slightly off-topic, consider sticking to std::string only with the convention that it is UTF-8 encoded and only convert to wide strings for APIs that require it.

Comment: I was worried to use a "non constrained" argument such as `StringT`: too many other things could get into.  But it is true that with some bit of checking on what `StringT` is, it could be really nice.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround seems to be to provide non-template overloads for `std::string` and `std::wstring` that delegate to the function template ([Demo at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96b1639f5a08b516)):

```
template <typename CharT, typename Traits, typename Allocator>
void foo(const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>&)
{}

inline void foo(const std::string& u) { foo<>(u); }
inline void foo(const std::wstring& u) { foo<>(u); }
```

Comment: *"The best workaround seems to be"* Why not use `std::wstring` literal suffixes?

Comment: @dyp: And what when the parameter is a C-style string that isn't a literal?

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, good point. I only considered the OP's test case.

Comment: Yes, I agree, overloads work well, with is what I meant at the end of my question.  Yet I meant to avoid that.